# "You are already signed in." will not disable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to implement an admin control panel for creating users. I have 2 devise models, admin and branch. I also have an admins controller which holds the creation view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :branch %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :branch, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>

<% end %>
```

I have then created my own devise registrations controller to overwrite/edit params and the create method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :cancel ]
  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:branch).permit(:branch, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:branch).permit(:branch, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

end
```

I am using this with the following routes:

```
  devise_for :branches, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_for :admins
```

Yet the problem still persists, when I am logged in as an admin and I am accessing the newwebsite view which is controlled by the admins controller, I fill in the form, hit submit and it fails to create the entry with the notice of: You are already signed in.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to pos the code from your models. I am assuming this issue has to do with the relationship between Branch and Admin. Just a hunch. Pasting in the model code might help me or others help you out. Possibly just a link to the repository?

Comment: Dont have a repos yet, there isn't any model relationships between the 2, I made both user types via the devise generator.

Comment: Devise does some loony things sometimes. It sounded as if there was some type of relationship between them in your description. You may just try "Logging out" as admin before creating branch. It could be your site works perfectly just that the behavior is different than you want or expected.

Comment: The creation of branches has to be only done by admins so that is not an option

Comment: the sign_up method makes you sign_in... override it in your controller

Comment: Which line is making me sign in? I cannot tell @knotito

Comment: sign_up(resource_name, resource)